# Fdisk in interactive mode

Tags: shell-script, scripting, partition, fdisk, partition-table

A few months ago, I had done a `.sh` script that used:

```
fdisk image.img <<EOF
o
n



+64M
a
1
t
6
n




w
EOF
```

It worked a few months ago. Now (a few updates later), it fails:

```
Command (m for help): Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x2bd95ecc.

Command (m for help): Partition type
    p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)    
    e   extended (container for logical partitions) 
Select (default p): 
Using default response p. 
Partition number (1-4, default 1): First sector (2048-2457599, default 2048): Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-2457599, default 2457599): 
Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 64 MiB. 

Command (m for help): Selected partition 1 
The bootable flag on partition 1 is enabled now. 

Command (m for help): 1: unknown command
```

Any idea what could solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your `1`.  Here you only have one partition and so the `a` command automatically selected it, and the `1` is unnecessary.

This is a problem with trying to use `fdisk` in this manner for scripted automation; the starting position may not be known or the user interface changes.

You may want to use `sfdisk` instead.  This is designed for scripting and you can define the partition table in absolute terms, rather than having to deal with potentially changing user interfaces.

Comment: Would you know how to translate this sequence into sfdisk ?

Comment: The nice thing with sfdisk is that you can manually create a setup, and then use `sfdisk` to dump it out (`sfdisk -d > partitionfile`) and then you can use that for further automation (`sfdisk < partitionfile`).  The man page explains this in detail.  Your program only needs to do that final `sfdisk image.img < partitonfile`.